# "resources.pri" file is missing or invalid when compiling sample of UWP with Desktop Extension

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

When compiling the sample [UWP with Desktop Extension Tutorial - Part 3](https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust/tree/master/UWP_FullTrust_3) in `VS2019`, I'm getting the following error. I `Cleaned` the project and did a `re-build` but still the same error. Also manually cleaned `bin` and `obj` folders as suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7e4655fd-120b-4731-86c8-560e551caa29/the-quotresourcespriquot-file-is-missing-or-invalid?forum=wpdevelop) but same error again:

> > Error PRI252 0xdef00071 - File C:\UWP_FullTrust_3\UWP\bin\x86\Debug\resources.pri not found. File C:\UWP-FullTrust-master\UWP_FullTrust_3\Package\GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE

**Configuration Manager Settings in `VS2019` for this Project**:

[image]
**My system**:

```
Windows 10 Pro - version 1809 - OS Build 17763.557
```

Comment: You need to check "Build" for the UWP project. Does that help with the error?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Your suggestion worked (thank you). You may want to add your comment as a `Response` with little details so it can help others as well. And I'll mark that as an `Answer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the solution's configuration manager you need to check the "Build" option also for the UWP project. This will resolve your build error.

Answer (score 0):

My bad fix: I just created an empty file.

For those who want to fumble: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/compile-resources-manually-with-makepri